# node.js websocket client can't connect to server code: 'ECONNRESET'

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

When I was using [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) npm package, I could use the same computer to create Server and connect client to the server.
But when I use client to connect to another websocket server,
I always get the below-mentioned error. server and client are in the same intranet.
I can make sure that this server could work because I use JavaScript to connect to it.
I'm using node.js version `v16.10.0`

```
error: Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:691:14)     
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:471:23)        
    at Socket.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task)_queues:83:21) {                                            _queues:83:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

Does anybody know why or have any idea?
Here is the client code

```
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.111:9000');
const object = { "message": "config_get" };
const data = JSON.stringify(object);

ws.on('error', (err) => console.log('error:', err));

ws.on('open', function open() {
    console.log('success');
});

ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log(`Server: ${message}`);
});
```

Comment: Did you find the origin of the issue ? As I'm too stuck in a similar bug

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late to answer to the issue you had but anyway I hope my solution might help someone or help you if you still need help and did not dump WebSocket aside !

I had the same issue as you with [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws)

```js
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:691:14)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:466:23)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:532:35)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1346:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

for a simple code as:

```js
const ws_session = new WebSocket(proto + '://' + data.ipAddress+":"+data.port);

ws_session.on('open', function open() {
    console.log('something');
});

ws_session.on('error', function open() {
    console.log('error');
});
                      
ws_session.on('message', function message(data) {
   console.log('received: %s', data);
});
```

I have tried [nodejs-websocket](https://github.com/sitegui/nodejs-websocket) and it worked fine !

```js
var options = {extraHeaders: {"origin": "Test"}};
var ws_session = new WebSocket.connect(proto + '://' + data.ipAddress+":"+data.port + '/', options);

ws_session.on('connect', function () {
    console.log("### Connected WS");
});

ws_session.on('text', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
})
```

So for me the issue was mainly caused by origin field which was missing in the GET HTTP/1.1 .To have a WebSocket Client working correctly with [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) just add the origin field like this:

```js
const ws_session = new WebSocket(proto + '://' + data.ipAddress+":"+data.port + '/', {
    origin:"Test"
});
```

A tcpdump of successful connection in case it might help.

```
tcpdump  -i any -s 0 -v -XX -n '(host 10.181.18.224) and (port 9001)'

21:37:00.235233 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 125, id 10420, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
10.181.18.224.60993 > 172.21.144.81.9001: Flags [S], cksum 0x9925 (correct), seq 4257508728, win 65500, options [mss 1310,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
        0x0000:  0000 0001 0006 0008 e3ff fd90 0000 0800  ................
        0x0010:  4500 0034 28b4 4000 7d06 7b14 0ab5 12e0  E..4(.@.}.{.....
        0x0020:  ac15 9051 ee41 2329 fdc4 6d78 0000 0000  ...Q.A#)..mx....
        0x0030:  8002 ffdc 9925 0000 0204 051e 0103 0308  .....%..........
        0x0040:  0101 0402                                ....

21:37:00.235267 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
172.21.144.81.9001 > 10.181.18.224.60993: Flags [S.], cksum 0x5a22 (incorrect -> 0x8999), seq 876928906, ack 4257508729, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 10], length 0
        0x0000:  0004 0001 0006 00a0 a5e2 51ce 0000 0800  ..........Q.....
        0x0010:  4500 0034 0000 4000 4006 e0c8 ac15 9051  E..4..@.@......Q
        0x0020:  0ab5 12e0 2329 ee41 3444 df8a fdc4 6d79  ....#).A4D....my
        0x0030:  8012 faf0 5a22 0000 0204 05b4 0101 0402  ....Z"..........
        0x0040:  0103 030a                                ...."

21:37:00.283778 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 125, id 10421, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
10.181.18.224.60993 > 172.21.144.81.9001: Flags [.], cksum 0xc15b (correct), ack 1, win 1028, length 0
        0x0000:  0000 0001 0006 0008 e3ff fd90 0000 0800  ................
        0x0010:  4500 0028 28b5 4000 7d06 7b1f 0ab5 12e0  E..((.@.}.{.....
        0x0020:  ac15 9051 ee41 2329 fdc4 6d79 3444 df8b  ...Q.A#)..my4D..
        0x0030:  5010 0404 c15b 0000 0000 0000 0000       P....[........

21:37:00.285814 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 125, id 10422, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 206)
10.181.18.224.60993 > 172.21.144.81.9001: Flags [P.], cksum 0x19f2 (correct), seq 1:167, ack 1, win 1028, length 166
        0x0000:  0000 0001 0006 0008 e3ff fd90 0000 0800  ................
        0x0010:  4500 00ce 28b6 4000 7d06 7a78 0ab5 12e0  E...(.@.}.zx....
        0x0020:  ac15 9051 ee41 2329 fdc4 6d79 3444 df8b  ...Q.A#)..my4D..
        0x0030:  5018 0404 19f2 0000 4745 5420 2f20 4854  P.......GET./.HT
        0x0040:  5450 2f31 2e31 0d0a 486f 7374 3a20 3137  TP/1.1..Host:.17
        0x0050:  322e 3231 2e31 3434 2e38 310d 0a55 7067  2.21.144.81..Upg
        0x0060:  7261 6465 3a20 7765 6273 6f63 6b65 740d  rade:.websocket.
        0x0070:  0a43 6f6e 6e65 6374 696f 6e3a 2055 7067  .Connection:.Upg
        0x0080:  7261 6465 0d0a 5365 632d 5765 6253 6f63  rade..Sec-WebSoc
        0x0090:  6b65 742d 4b65 793a 2044 354d 6c68 5144  ket-Key:.D5MlhQD
        0x00a0:  6d34 775a 6f6b 714c 4e74 4b45 4c4c 513d  m4wZokqLNtKELLQ=
        0x00b0:  3d0d 0a53 6563 2d57 6562 536f 636b 6574  =..Sec-WebSocket
        0x00c0:  2d56 6572 7369 6f6e 3a20 3133 0d0a 6f72  -Version:.13..or
        0x00d0:  6967 696e 3a20 5465 7374 0d0a 0d0a       igin:.Test....

21:37:00.285843 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 19753, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
172.21.144.81.9001 > 10.181.18.224.60993: Flags [.], cksum 0x5a16 (incorrect -> 0xc47a), ack 167, win 63, length 0
        0x0000:  0004 0001 0006 00a0 a5e2 51ce 0000 0800  ..........Q.....
        0x0010:  4500 0028 4d29 4000 4006 93ab ac15 9051  E..(M)@.@......Q
        0x0020:  0ab5 12e0 2329 ee41 3444 df8b fdc4 6e1f  ....#).A4D....n.
        0x0030:  5010 003f 5a16 0000                      P..?Z...


21:37:00.286336 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 19754, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 169)
172.21.144.81.9001 > 10.181.18.224.60993: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5a97 (incorrect -> 0xc525), seq 1:130, ack 167, win 63, length 129
        0x0000:  0004 0001 0006 00a0 a5e2 51ce 0000 0800  ..........Q.....
        0x0010:  4500 00a9 4d2a 4000 4006 9329 ac15 9051  E...M*@.@..)...Q
        0x0020:  0ab5 12e0 2329 ee41 3444 df8b fdc4 6e1f  ....#).A4D....n.
        0x0030:  5018 003f 5a97 0000 4854 5450 2f31 2e31  P..?Z...HTTP/1.1
        0x0040:  2031 3031 2053 7769 7463 6869 6e67 2050  .101.Switching.P
        0x0050:  726f 746f 636f 6c73 0d0a 5570 6772 6164  rotocols..Upgrad
        0x0060:  653a 2077 6562 736f 636b 6574 0d0a 436f  e:.websocket..Co
        0x0070:  6e6e 6563 7469 6f6e 3a20 5570 6772 6164  nnection:.Upgrad
        0x0080:  650d 0a53 6563 2d57 6562 536f 636b 6574  e..Sec-WebSocket
        0x0090:  2d41 6363 6570 743a 2064 5946 2f33 6a4b  -Accept:.dYF/3jK
        0x00a0:  487a 3058 496d 4c6f 616c 6532 3449 7261  Hz0XImLoale24Ira
        0x00b0:  4666 3263 3d0d 0a0d 0a                   Ff2c=....

21:37:00.387744 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 125, id 10425, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
10.181.18.224.60993 > 172.21.144.81.9001: Flags [.], cksum 0xc034 (correct), ack 130, win 1028, length 0
        0x0000:  0000 0001 0006 0008 e3ff fd90 0000 0800  ................
        0x0010:  4500 0028 28b9 4000 7d06 7b1b 0ab5 12e0  E..((.@.}.{.....
        0x0020:  ac15 9051 ee41 2329 fdc4 6e1f 3444 e00c  ...Q.A#)..n.4D..
        0x0030:  5010 0404 c034 0000 0000 0000 0000       P....4........

21:37:00.387772 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 19755, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 128)
172.21.144.81.9001 > 10.181.18.224.60993: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5a6e (incorrect -> 0xb0db), seq 130:218, ack 167, win 63, length 88
        0x0000:  0004 0001 0006 00a0 a5e2 51ce 0000 0800  ..........Q.....
        0x0010:  4500 0080 4d2b 4000 4006 9351 ac15 9051  E...M+@.@..Q...Q
        0x0020:  0ab5 12e0 2329 ee41 3444 e00c fdc4 6e1f  ....#).A4D....n.
        0x0030:  5018 003f 5a6e 0000 8156 7b22 6d65 7373  P..?Zn...V{"mess
        0x0040:  6167 6522 3a22 7265 6164 7922 2c22 7479  age":"ready","ty
        0x0050:  7065 223a 2245 4e42 222c 226e 616d 6522  pe":"ENB","name"
        0x0060:  3a22 454e 4222 2c22 7665 7273 696f 6e22  :"ENB","version"
        0x0070:  3a22 3230 3231 2d30 392d 3138 222c 2274  :"2021-09-18","t
        0x0080:  696d 6522 3a34 3433 3334 312e 3937 357d  ime":443341.975}

21:37:00.477690 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 125, id 10427, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
10.181.18.224.60993 > 172.21.144.81.9001: Flags [.], cksum 0xbfdd (correct), ack 218, win 1027, length 0
        0x0000:  0000 0001 0006 0008 e3ff fd90 0000 0800  ................
        0x0010:  4500 0028 28bb 4000 7d06 7b19 0ab5 12e0  E..((.@.}.{.....
        0x0020:  ac15 9051 ee41 2329 fdc4 6e1f 3444 e064  ...Q.A#)..n.4D.d
        0x0030:  5010 0403 bfdd 0000 0000 0000 0000       P.............
```